# Auth0 redirect loop after auth.loginWithRedirect() - @auth0/auth0-spa-js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I'm currently switching the authentication of my (React) application from the Auth0 react SDK to the normal SPA SDK (as I don't like the way tokens are fetched in the react SDK)

The issue I'm facing now is that when I sign in to the application I'm stuck in an endless redirection loop that is caused (I think) by the component below. Some context: the router uses protected routes that will redirect the user to the /login route that handles the authentication. Inside the component bellow `auth.isAuthenticated()` always returns false... That's why `auth.loginWithRedirect()` is called. But I can't see how to solve this...

```
const LoginRoute: React.FunctionComponent<any> = ({ ...props }) => {
  const { isLoggedIn, loading } = useSelector(userSelector);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleAsyncLogin = async () => {
      const isAuthenticated = await auth.isAuthenticated();
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        // Auth0 says we are logged in, so we only need to store the user in the store
        dispatch(login());
      } else if (!!auth && !loading) {
        // We are *not* logged in. Go to Auth0 login page.
        await auth?.loginWithRedirect();
      }
    };
    handleAsyncLogin();
  }, [dispatch, loading]);

  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      component={() => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          console.log("Is Logged In");
          // We are *definitely* logged in, go to projects
          return <Redirect to="/questionsFromMe" />;
        }
        if (loading) {
          return <Loader />;
        }
        return <div />;
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Please help me out! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `auth.isAuthenticated()` returns false even after successful login from auth0? Then you will definitely will be in loop.

Comment: I think your problem stems from "login()" which we can't see what it does or where it comes from in the code shown above. What's probably happening is the useEffect is getting triggered over and over again because of the dispatch. In addition, you're always trying to perform a login, even when the user is authenticated. the useAuth0 hook automatically populates you the user variable which you can use to extract all the info you need.

Comment: Hello, was this ever solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **'Application Type'** to a value that **suits your app** in auth0 application properties page if you have not already.
[image]